# How to check total operating hours for Cisco Catalyst switches?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst

We bought about 25 Cisco Catalyst (9300 & 9500) switches and about 200+ SFPs from a distributor with whom we've had trouble in the past - i.e. they sent us refurbished hardware when we ordered new.

During our initial checks, we found ~1% of SFPs malfunctioning and have two switches (1x 9300, 1x9500) with defective PSUs.

Is there a way to read the total runtime (over the lifetime of each device) for switches, their PSUs, and SFPs?
Or some other information that would let me know (or give a strong indication) whether the hardware we bought is actually new or old/refurbished?

Answer (score 1):

Check the manufactured date to make sure.

CISCO material usually don't lay 2/3 years in a stock house, so the date might give you an idea of the age and if refurbished.

You can use cisco sn lookup tool if you have a valid login to their website; https://cway.cisco.com/sncheck/

To find the MFG date manually you can decode the SN too; quote from [here](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/cisco-serial-number-lookups/td-p/1375234);

> There's a fairly easy way to derive the manufacture date if you happen
> to know the serial number.
>
> The serial number will be in the format: ‘LLLYYWWSSSS’; where ‘YY’ is
> the year of manufacture and ‘WW’ is the week of manufacture.  The date
> code can be found in the 4 middle digits of the serial number.  In the
> case of serial number SAD08300D4W, ‘08’ is the year code and ‘30’ is
> the week code. You can then decode the date use the following:
>
> Here are the Manufacturing Year Codes:
>
> ```
>             01 = 1997                              06 = 2002                              11 = 2007                              16 = 2012
>
>             02 = 1998                              07 = 2003                              12 = 2008                              17 = 2013
>
>             03 = 1999                              08 = 2004                              13 = 2009                              18 = 2014
>
>             04 = 2000                              09 = 2005                              14 = 2010                              19 = 2015
>
>             05 = 2001                              10 = 2006                              15 = 2011                              20 = 2016
> ```
>
> And here are the Manufacturing Week Codes:
>
> ```
>             1-5 : January                  15-18 : April                        28-31 : July                          41-44 : October
>
>             6-9 : February                19-22 : May                         32-35 : August                   45-48 : November
>
>             10-14 : March                 23-27 : June                        36-40 : September           49-52 : December
> ```

Comment: What if "YY" in your example is "F0"?
I found that source through Google, but sadly it didn't quite help me.